# One Dimensional Game of Life

Tags: algorithm, bit-shift, conways-game-of-life

The problem is based on a spin-off of the Conway's game of life.
Click [here](https://www.codechef.com/COOK04/problems/LIFE)

Based on the solution provided by the author

```
 `#include <cstdio>
  #include <cstring>

  int N;
  long long rot(long long x, int amt){
    return ((x<<amt)|(x>>(N-amt)))&((1ll<<N)-1);
}

   int main(){
    char in[51];
    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    while(T--){
        scanf("%s", in);
        N=strlen(in);
        long long cur=0, orig=0;
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            cur|=(long long)(in[i]-'0')<<i;
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            if((i%3)!=(2*N%3))
                orig^=rot(cur, i);
        if((N%3)==0){
            if(orig==0)
                puts("Multiple solutions");
            else
                puts("No solution");
        }else{
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
                putchar('0'+((orig>>i)&1));
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
`
```

Can you explain what the "if" condition `if((i%3)!=(2*N%3))` helps to achieve.

Also can you elaborate the second solution provided in the editorial [https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/4202/life-editorial?sort=oldest] because the simulation step `(A<<<1)^A^(A>>>1)` does not satisfy any of the test cases.